# How to replace text when the string exactly matches the search

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to remove words from chat text:

```
for(var i =0; i <db.banned_words.length ;i++){
    cleaned_msg = cleaned_msg.replace(new RegExp(db.banned_words[i], 'g'), '');
}
```

The problem is if cleaned_msg has only one of the banned words, it does not remove it from cleaned_msg.

ex;
cleaned_msg = 'duck' ; if duck is one of the banned words, then, after the replace, cleaned_msg should be '', but it is 'duck'.

If cleaned_message has any other spaces or characters, it works fine. ex; duckie returns 'ie'; ' duck' returns ' '.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/cQWZR. Aside from that, I'm not sure why you're using the `RegExp` constructor at all; it's not necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/84T9T.

Comment: It should work as is... please note that your regex is case-sensitive.

Comment: can you post the actual regular expressions you're using?

Comment: @MattBall, It will only replace a single occurence of the banned words without using a regex with the `g` flag.

Comment: @basilikum I'm not sure what you are asking. The regexp is right there in the code.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss, He wants to know what is `db.banned_words[i]`

Comment: @LeeLoftiss yes, what plalx said...the content of the array db.banned_words.

Comment: They are just individual words. Mat Ball was correct, what he has works. Very strange.

Comment: if db.banned_words is an array of strings (words) then all you need to do is cleaned_msg.replace(db.banned_words[i], '');

Comment: My apologies everyone for the wild goose chase. The issue stemmed from another part of my code. Thanks to you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should be working so your issue probably lies somewhere else. However may I suggest you a different approach?

```
var banned_words = ['duck', 'cool', 'test'],
    banned_words_rx = new RegExp('\\b(' + banned_words.join('|') + ')\\b', 'gi');

'this duck is very cool, so cool that I used it to test this thing'.replace(banned_words_rx, '');
```

Comment: I thought the same but it would not replace ducking :-) And no multi line

Comment: Thanks Plalx. The problem was with another part of my code.

Comment: Nice way to use the OR operator, but why the word boundry? if the first word in the array is duck and I use motherducker than it would not replace that word.

Comment: @HMR, I just assumed that he just wanted to replace whole matches. Lee, you can remove the word boundaries if you want to replace these words, even if they are part of other words.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. And, with a suggestion from HMR, I created the following RegExp when the banned words are first loaded, instead of each time they are checked -banned_words = new RegExp(words.join('|'), 'gi') - Thank to you both for the pointers.

Comment: BTW, do you guys know how I could change this so that with the banned word 'duck', the entire word motherducker would be removed?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss, Yeah, Try something like this 'test motherducker test2 superducker'.replace(/[^\s]*duck[^\s]*/g, '');

Comment: Thanks again Plalx, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Myabe you could get some performance benefit when you compile your regex when the page loads and use it later. Also make it case insensitive and multi line. Then there is a problem that when your banned words array has a character that's considered a special character in regexp your replace will not behave as it should:

```
var replacer={
  bannedR=[],
  init:function(){
    for(var i =0; i <db.banned_words.length ;i++){
      replacer.bannedR.push(new RegExp(db.banned_words[i]
        .replace(/([-()\[\]{}+?*.$\^|,:#<!\\])/g, '\\$1')
        .replace(/\x08/g, '\\x08'), 'igm');
    }  
  },
  replace:function(msg){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<replacer.bannedR.length;i++){
      msg=msg.replace(replacer.bannedR[i],'');
    }
    return msg;
  }
}
replacer.init();
```

Answer (score -1):

if db.banned_words is an array of strings (words) then all you need to do is cleaned_msg.replace(db.banned_words[i], '');

http://jsfiddle.net/ijackson/yjV3e/

`var banned_words = ['badword','duck'];
    var cleaned_msg = "This is a long string containing a few bad words such as badword and duck";`

```
for(var i =0; i <banned_words.length ;i++){
    cleaned_msg = cleaned_msg.replace(banned_words[i], '');
}
```

document.getElementById('output').value = cleaned_msg;

Comment: It would be case sensiteve and only replaces the first ocurence: "DUCK duck duck".replace("duck","nope")==="DUCK nope duck"//true